# Strip Drupal Page Template from CiviCRM Contribution Page

Tags: drupal, custom-templates

I want to strip all Drupal navigation etc coming from page.tpl.php for a particular contribution page and all the associated pages of the contribution process. But all just for one contribution page.

In Drupal I know how to create template suggestions for a Drupal theme that will apply only to a specific path. But I don't thing the template suggestions can handle the query part of the CiviCRM URL.

Ideas?

Comment: Thanks so much. I think you may have missed the part of my question that said, "for a particular contribution page." Generally I want CiviCRM to use the Drupal theme. However, on a particular contribution page and its associated pages I want different theming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [themekey module is the answer](https://www.drupal.org/project/themekey). ThemeKey can handle query strings.

Comment: Themekey can handle query strings, but to have it kick in on later phases of the contribute page you'll want [Themekey CiviCRM](https://github.com/fuzionnz/themekey_civicrm) as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can assign CiviCRM to use the default template in your Drupal theme settings. The default theme doesn't engage your Drupal theme and menu system.

In Drupal 7, it's https://www.example.com/admin/appearance, then scroll down to the bottom of the page and you can set your theme for CiviCRM.

[image]

If you want to retain your template but just strip out navigation, you may need to make a new template based on it for CiviCRM to use and assign it.